# open template.html: The system cannot find the file specified Error in GoLang

Tags: go

I'm pretty new to go and programming in general. I tried to create a website using Go, but somehow it does not read my HTML template. what did I do wrong??
[Here's the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIB5M.png)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var data = map[string]string{
            "Name":    "john wick",
            "Message": "have a nice day",
        }

        var t, err = template.ParseFiles("template.html")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return
        }

        t.Execute(w, data)
    })

    fmt.Println("starting web server at http://localhost:8080/")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: You are running your code from different directory; It will look for template file in current directory you are in

Comment: File names are relative to the current working directory, not the .go file where the filename is used.

Comment: how do i check it? both are in web directory

Comment: Add this line to the beginning of `main()`:  `fmt.Println(os.Getwd())`.  I think you will find that the working directory is not the web directory.